How to examine scoped data service objects in the Immediate Window of a WASM Visual Studio app?
My WASM app developed with VS Community 2022 v 17.10.1 creates a scoped data Service (via  builder.Services.AddScoped() in Program.cs in which MyData is a class containing only properties).
At breakpoints, I can hover the cursor over references to MyData to see the property values, but if I enter "MyData;" in the Immediate Window, I get "Uncaught Cannot evaluate '(MyData;".  I have no idea what the "(" nor single "'" are about.  I've also tried entering "MyData);" but get the same message showing "'(MyData);".  Finally, I don't get anything (sometimes) if I hover the cursor over a reference to one of MyData's properties.  I can only examine all of MyData via hover.  This is a real productivity hit.  Thanks for any help you can provide.
